# How to create a very specific data diagram using Python

Tags: python, visualization

I would like to make a diagram in Python similar to the one shown below. From what I've seen so far, there is no a library that I could use directly. Can you suggest me where to start from, for example, would it be worth to improvise by stacking horizontally multiple subplots. Is there maybe a better approach?

Thanks!

[image: slackdiagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the name you're looking for is `Parallel Coordinates Plot`.

I'm sure Plotly supports it and there are tutorials online for other libraries as well.

Let me know if this helps.

Edit: and judging by [this image](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/plotly-tutorials/plotly-documentation/images/python_parcoords_ex1.gif) from [Plotly's docs](https://plot.ly/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/) your example image comes from there.

Comment: yes, that is it, I found the code here https://plot.ly/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/ Many thanks!